# How to check if response header contains certain headers powershell

Tags: powershell, web, request

I'm using iwr to make a request like so:

```
iwr "http://someapi/param" -UseBasicParsing -Method Head
```

This gets me the headers which looks something like this:

```
$var1 = "Timing-Allow-Origin: *
X-CID: 1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 43
Cache-Control: public,max-age=172800
Content-Type: image/gif
Other headers
```

How do I check if the headers contain this:

```
"Timing-Allow-Origin"="*"
"Cache-Control"="public,max-age=172800"
```

I tried

```
$var2.RawContent = iwr "http://someapi/param" -UseBasicParsing -Method Head
Write-Host ($var2.RawContent -like "*Timing-Allow-Origin: *")
```

But this returns false for some reason. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Headers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) returned from `Invoke-Webrequest` is a [IDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can test by retrieving the value of the key you need.

```
$response = iwr "http://someapi/param" -UseBasicParsing -Method Head
if ($response.Headers["Cache-Control"] -eq "public,max-age=172800") {
    Write-Output "Found"
} else {
    Write-Output "Not found"
}
```